# Is combinational logic affected by the clock in FPGA?

Tags: digital-logic, fpga, clock, logic-gates

I have a question whether a computational logic expression is affected by the clock if it is in a process and all the inputs are listed in the sensitivity list.  If a change happens in one of the inputs, it will just change without having to wait for the next clock cycle?

I also have a question which is related, whether if for example you have a case statement which is not in a process will it be affected by the clock or if a change happens in one of the inputs it will automatically change without having to wait for the next clock cycle.

Comment: Could you *please* parse your text into sensible questions. End a question with a question mark (?) and put them last. What you have right now is clear as mud.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is combinational, then not it is not affected by the clock.

For example in VHDL

```
COMB_PROCESS : Process(A,B)
begin
   Y <= A xor B;
end process;
```

The sensitivity list is only useful for the simulation tools, it is not used by the synthesizer. So even if you put

```
COMB_PROCESS_WITH_WRONG_SENSITIVITY : Process(A,B, CLK)
begin
   Y <= A xor B;
end process;
```

the result will be the same. Except your simulator will evaluate this process every time the clock changes which is not the best.

And for your information, with simple combinational logic, it is often easier not to use processes instead :

```
Y <= A xor B;
```

Comment: Would it be ok if I say that the clock does not affect for example a conditional statement which is outside a process which is mapping a particular input to a particular output.  So if an input changes, the output would change at that instant (maybe some propagation delay) but it would not wait for the next clock cycle.

Comment: Exactly, it would only be affected by the propagation delay.

Comment: Is there any guarantee that a compiler given such code would generate logic that won't be affected *even momentarily* by changes in clk?

Comment: There could be some "cross-talk", an analog phenomenon, depending on the routing of said clock in your FPGA and the combinational inputs/outputs.